# Split an array into new arrays (each with a unique name)

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration, slice

I'm trying to slice an array into equal sizes (rounded down) and save each section to respective variables.

The method *each_slice* has worked to grab n-sized blocks. However I can't think of a way to:

1. iterate over the each's blocks' "sub index"
2. create a new array for each and give each a unique name.

   ```
   letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]

      def groups_of_five(array)
      split_array = array.each_slice(5).to_a

      #something like the following:
      #array(n) = Array[split_array.each {|x| x}]

      end 
   end
   ```

The output I'm hoping for:

```
groups_of_five(letters)
=> array1: ["a,"b","c","d","e"]
=> array2: ["f","g","h","i","j"]
=> array3: ["k","l","m","n"]
```

Comment: you want from groups_of_five(letters),  a hash structure, like `{array1: ["a,"b","c","d","e"],array2: ["f","g","h","i","j"]}` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `each_slice` with `with_index` and you'll have everything you need:

```
letters.each_slice(5).with_index(1) do |group, index| 
  puts "array#{index}: #{group.inspect}"
end
```

Output is:

```
array1: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
array2: ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
array3: ["k", "l", "m", "n"]
```

It's no longer possible to set local variable dynamically in Ruby versions greather than 1.8, so if you want to assign to variables it will have to be instance variables or you could output a Hash.

The following will create instance variables:

```
def groups_of_five(array)
  array.each_slice(5).with_index(1) do |group, index| 
    instance_variable_set "@array#{index}".to_sym, group
  end
end

groups_of_five(letters)
puts @array1 #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
puts @array2 #=> ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
puts @array3 #=> ["k", "l", "m", "n"]
```

Or this will output a Hash:

```
def groups_of_five(array)
  hash = {}
  array.each_slice(5).with_index(1) do |group, index| 
    hash["array#{index}".to_sym] = group
  end
  hash
end

hash = groups_of_five(letters)
puts hash[:array1] #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
puts hash[:array2] #=> ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
puts hash[:array3] #=> ["k", "l", "m", "n"]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Now to understand what's going on! I like the use of "group" and "index". Earlier I called it "sub group" but seems like a much clearer convention. I suppose I'm unclear on how this is creating new arrays. I see it <puts> new lines. But are those actual arrays?

Comment: Updated with a couple of new examples.  I would personally go with the last hash output option.

Comment: You can write `with_index(1)` to have the index begin at `1`. (That's not an option with `each_with_index`).

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, I was not aware of that one. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. I'm still a little curious how this is creating new arrays. Is there some trickery in the <puts> statement that I'm not seeing? Thanks for helping a beginner out.

Comment: @TCannadySF, the first example is just outputting via puts - it is not creating any variables.  See the 2nd example for how to create dynamic instance variables.

Comment: You might think this is pushing it, but you could write: `def groups_of_five(array); array.each_slice(5).with_index(1).with_object({}) do |(group, index),hash| hash["array#{index}".to_sym] = group; end; end`.

Comment: Thanks for this @CarySwoveland. Both the instance variable and hash options are interesting, thanks for spelling them out. The instance variable one is a little new to me, mainly the instance_variable_set part. I think I'll avoid going down that path until I learn a little more about it. Regarding the hash approach, I think I get what's going on. My only thought is that I'd like a call to the method (groups_of_five) to return all the groups and their names. How could you update the code, mainly in the case that you don't know how many groups you'll have? EG, puts n-groups (keys and values)?

Comment: That's what it's already doing.  `hash = groups_of_five(letters)`, then `hash.keys` will give you the group names.

Comment: You may be confusing me with infused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a hash structure to return from groups_of_five(letters), here's the solution

```
def groups_of_five(array)
   split_array = letters.each_slice(5).to_a
   split_array.reduce({}){ |i,a|
       index = split_array.index(a) + 1
       i["array#{index}"] = a; i
   }
end

# groups_of_five(letters)
#=> {"array1"=>["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], "array2"=>["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"], "array3"=>["k", "l", "m", "n"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
def group_em(a,n)
  arr = a.dup
  (1..(arr.size.to_f/n).ceil).each_with_object({}) { |i,h|
    h["array#{i}"] = arr.shift(n) }
end

group_em(letters,1)
  #=> {"array1"=>["a"], "array2"=>["b"],...,"array14"=>["n"]} 
group_em(letters,2)
  #=> {"array1"=>["a", "b"], "array2"=>["c", "d"],...,"array7"=>["m", "n"]} 
group_em(letters,5)
  #=> {"array1"=>["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  #    "array2"=>["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
  #    "array3"=>["k", "l", "m", "n"]}
```

A variant is:

```
def group_em(arr,n)
  (1..(arr.size.to_f/n).ceil).zip(arr.each_slice(n).to_a)
    .each_with_object({}) { |(i,a),h| h["array#{i}"]=>a) }
end
```